# Angular routes partial to 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When loading a page of my app directly to the link /pl/param1 all the files fail to load because angular prepends the directories. How can I fix it?

```
angular.module('html5app', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function config ($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        //enabling HTML5 mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

        //setting up routes
        $routeProvider.when('/',{ templateUrl: '/partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'});
        $routeProvider.when('/about',{ templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'});
        $routeProvider.when('/pl',{ templateUrl: '/partials/plPartials/pl.html'});
        $routeProvider.when('/pl/:name',{ templateUrl: '/partials/plPartials/pl.html', controller: 'PlCtrl as plDetail'});
    }]);
```

Failed to load url (why is pl getting stuck after the port number?):

```
http://localhost:3000/pl/js/app.js
```

Attached SEO server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//initialize static server that will spit out contents of public folder
app.use('/', function(){
    var staticPath = __dirname + '/',
        req = arguments[0];

    if(/_escaped_fragment_=/.test(req.url)){ // testing if url contains '_escaped_fragment_=' part
        req.url = req.url.replace(/\?.*$/,'').replace(/\/+$/,''); // if it does, then strip it

        // if url became empty then it means 'http://someurl/?_escaped_fragment_=' was requested,
        // so we need to return pre-rendered index.html, otherwise we should add '.html' extension
        // so that it would return 'posts.html' when http://someurl/posts?_escaped_fragment_= is requested
        req.url += (req.url === '') ? '/index.html' : '.html';
        staticPath += 'snapshots'; // making '/snapshots' the base directory of our static server
    } else {
        staticPath += 'public'; // if it's a regular link, then initialize static server in '/public' directory
    }
    express.static(staticPath).apply(this, arguments);
});

//send our main angular html file if any link without dot is requested, e.g. 'http://someurl/about'
//this is our actual server side redirect, we don't send index.html when there's dot in link assuming such a request
//is for static data like .js, .css or .html
app.get('/[^\.]+$', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        .sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000); //the express server will start on port 9823
console.log('\nangular SEO server started on port 3000');
```

Comment: Not enough information provided

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: Using base tag? Expected url's? Server mod rewrite details etc. Issue won't likely be with angular, will likely be something else

Comment: app works one way (if I start at the home page and work into it. But if I jump into a page, it prepends that url before all the ng-includes

Comment: this is a standalone app right now, so it's very basic

Comment: so you are saying it loads fine at app entry point?

Comment: correct. Only fails if I skip it. But when I change $location then the partials in that new .html file also prepend the path.

Comment: Did you configure mod rewrite on server to account for html5 mode virtual directories? Try the page without html5mode and use hash to test it

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I edited the question with the simple SEO server I'm using

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but could you show how your index.html is including the other files? Are they relative to current location or from the App root - i.e. do their path names start with slash '/' or not?

Comment: They son't start with a /

Comment: Added the slash and it works well! Thanks. Feel free to add the answer